# unable to access EC2 instance created using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have been following [youtube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLB_c_ayRMo&t=6069s) to learn terraform and have followed each steps.
After running terraform apply it was able to setup everything as expected. I have verified this on aws console. But while trying to access the public ip it is saying connection refused.

Below is the content of my main.tf file.

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-east-1"
  access_key = "ACCESS-KEY"
  secret_key = "SECERT-KEY"
}

# VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "prod-vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  tags = {
      Name = "production"
  }
}

# create internet gateway 
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name : "Prod gateway"
  }
}

# create custom route table 

resource "aws_route_table" "prod-route-table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id

  route {
      cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
      gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }

  route {
      ipv6_cidr_block        = "::/0"
      gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Prod"
  }
}

# Create a subnet 

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-1" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id
    cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
    availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
    map_public_ip_on_launch = true

    tags = {
        Name = "prod-subnet"
    }
}

# Associate subnet with Route Table 

resource "aws_route_table_association" "a" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet-1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.prod-route-table.id
}

# Create Security Group to allow port 22, 80, 443

resource "aws_security_group" "allow_web" {
  name        = "allow_web_traffic"
  description = "Allow Web traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id

  ingress {
      description      = "HTTPS"
      from_port        = 443
      to_port          = 443
      protocol         = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

  ingress {
      description      = "HTTP"
      from_port        = 80
      to_port          = 80
      protocol         = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
  ingress {
      description      = "SSH"
      from_port        = 2
      to_port          = 2
      protocol         = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

  egress {
      from_port        = 0
      to_port          = 0
      protocol         = "-1"
      cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
    }

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_web"
  }
}

# Create a network interface with an ip in the subnet that was created earlier 

resource "aws_network_interface" "web-server-nic" {
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.subnet-1.id
  private_ips     = ["10.0.1.50"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow_web.id]

  tags = {
    Name : "prod-network-interface"
  }
}

# Assign an elastic ip to the network interface created in previous step

resource "aws_eip" "one" {
  vpc                       = true
  network_interface         = aws_network_interface.web-server-nic.id
  associate_with_private_ip = "10.0.1.50"
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.gw, aws_instance.web-server-instance]

  tags = {
    Name : "Prod-Elastic-ip"
  }
}

# Create Ubuntu server and install/enable apache2

resource "aws_instance" "web-server-instance" {
    ami = "ami-0747bdcabd34c712a"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
    key_name = "main-key"

    network_interface {
        device_index = 0
        network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.web-server-nic.id
    }

    user_data = <<-EOF
        #! /bin/bash
        sudo apt update -y 
        sudo apt install apache2
        sudo bash -c 'echo your very first web server > /var/www/html/index.html'
        EOF

    tags = {
      Name : "Web-Server"
    }    
}
```

Comment: SSH port is 22, not 2

Comment: Is web server running and listening the specified ports? Check it over the server console using "curl" or "wget".

Comment: If you configure VPC to assign public IPs, why do you need elastic IP?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and help @30thh. I am still learning and exploring these stuffs so I just followed the tutorial. But I will explore more on what you have suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `-y` in your user data, so your user-data will just hang for confirmation. It should be:

```
sudo apt install -y apache2
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin for quick help. 
If someone else is following the same tutorial and is facing some issues, I am mentioning an issue which I faced. While writing script for elastic ip there was an error and I searched and figured that it is better to put dependency on aws instance as well. you can refer this small change in my script.
`resource "aws_eip" "one" {
  ...
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.gw, **aws_instance.web-server-instance**]

  tags = {
    Name : "Prod-Elastic-ip"
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You missed that another command need to start this apache2 after installed it

```
sudo systemctl start apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

It also seems that the SSH port on the security group is not configured correctly. It should probably read `22` instead of `2` for both `from_port` and `to_port`.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem here is at security group. For SSH configuration you should open port `22`, the default SSH port.

```
  ingress {
      description      = "SSH"
      from_port        = 22
      to_port          = 22
      protocol         = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
```

Besides that, you should fix your userdata with:

```
        #! /bin/bash
        sudo apt update -y 
        sudo apt install apache2 -y
        sudo systemctl start apache2
        sudo bash -c 'echo your very first web server > /var/www/html/index.html'
```

I hope this can help you and other people with the same or similar issue.